# Creating a new text field based on values in an existing text field

Tags: ms-access

I have a question about creating fields in Access. Say I have a text field titled "Code" with the following values.

```
A31
A94
B17
C28
X23
X38
Y59
Y28
Z40
```

Let's say I wanted to create a new text field called "Color" with values based on the "Code" field so that all Code records starting with A or X are assigned a Color value of Red, records starting with B or Y are assigned a Color value of Yellow, and all Code records starting with C or Z are assigned a Color value of Blue. Is such a thing possible? Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE FieldNameHere LIKE "B*" Or FieldNameHere Like ...` make an atempt and then come back.

Comment: I won't be able to try it until I get into work tomorrow (just getting jump-started on some work this afternoon). Thanks for the advice.

I'm not super familiar with SQL, what statement would I use to assign the actual color value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in three rounds as @Remou suggests, or, since it is relatively few values you are testing against, you can stuff it all into an immediate if function (change tablename from `Table1` to whatever your table is called and paste this in to your sql view of your query editor:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.code, IIf(Left([code],1) In ('A','X'),"Red",IIf(Left([code],1) In ('B','Y'),"Yellow",IIf(Left([code],1) In ('C','Z'),"Blue",""))) AS Expr1
FROM Table1;
```